What is the best way to convert positive voltage to negative while consuming the smallest amount of power?
I would like to power a circuit from a battery, which requires a negative supply as well as the positive supply I have.
What is the best way to get a negative voltage from a positive power supply?
The power circuit must be able to produce -2.5 V from a 2.5 V supply.
The max output current will be low. I am using an ADA4051 autozero op-amp that draws a quiescent current of Iq = 15 uA. It is for a sensor application where the sensor outputs -0.4..0.4 V into the op-amp inputs. The op-amp has to add a negative offset voltage to the sensor voltage. The op-amp output drives an ADC with a 0..3  input range.
EDIT: I think the idea of a charge pump is good. I will go with it for now.

It depends on a lot of details you haven't given.

list them. idk what you need to know. if i did, i would've given them.

Input voltage, output voltage, output current to start with.

Input voltage, output voltage, maximum output current, do you need good low-current efficiency too (e.g. when the device is in sleep mode), budget, any special considerations around switching frequency, etc.

Describe your application a bit, too. Maybe a virtual ground would be a better fit than  dual power rails.

Edit this information into your question. Don't just leave it in comments.

You can add next (small) battery for negative rail.

Also is re-designing your positive supply circuit a possibility? There are switching topologies that produces dual outputs directly.

I can redesign the positive supply circuit. It would need to operate off of 1 battery though.

Where each rail takes either a similar current, or a low current, it's often better to split the battery voltage to provide a virtual ground somewhere between the rails.
This is not the case if the currents are very unbalanced, as the current for the high current rail will be voltage-dropped across the voltage of the low current rail.
For very low currents on the other rail, a charge pump usually provides the lowest power solution. If you already have a switchmode supply providing your main rail from the battery, you can often use its switching node for the AC input of the charge pump.
